# Is xgcd faster than Fermat for calculating $d$ in RSA?

Tags: rsa, complexity

I want to calculate $d$ from $e$ when generating RSA keys.

What is faster?

- Calculating $\operatorname{xgcd}(e,p)$ and $\operatorname{xgcd}(e,q)$ and CRT.
- **Or** calculating $e^{p-2}\bmod p$ and $e^{q-2}\bmod q$ and CRT.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to calculate the complexity here.

Comment: Typically, when creating an RSA private/public key pair, almost all the time is taken searching for primes; the tiny amount of time taken computing $d$ (or $dp$ and $dq$) is negligible; either method you cite would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The extended Euclidean algorithm ($\operatorname{xgcd}$), when applied to $p$ and $e<p$, uses at most $\lceil\log_\phi(\sqrt5(p+1))\rceil-2\in\mathcal O(\log p)$ divisions in $\mathbb Z$. (This is [Knuth's corollary to Lamé's theorem](http://cut-the-knot.org/blue/LamesTheorem.shtml).)
- Using Fermat's little theorem and square-and-multiply exponentiation on $e$ modulo $p$ takes at most $2\cdot\lfloor\log_2(p-2)\rfloor\in\mathcal O(\log p)$ multiplications **in $\mathbb F_p$**.

Therefore, both methods are ***asymptotically*** equivalent. However, there are some practical benefits when using $\operatorname{xgcd}$:

- The involved numbers' bit length decreases very quickly.
- A division with remainder is generally cheaper than a multiplication followed by a modulo operation.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how you got to these complexities?